# VB.net cannot inherit

Tags: vb.net

I am fairly new to VB.net, I cannot compile this code, and I don't get why.

```
MustInherit Class Poligono

    Protected p_cant_Lados As Integer
    Public Property cant_Lados() As Integer
        Get
            Return p_cant_Lados
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            p_cant_Lados = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public MustOverride Function obtenerPerimetro()
    Public MustOverride Function cargarLados()

End Class

Public Class Triangulo
    Inherits Poligono

    Private lado1 As Integer
    Private lado2 As Integer
    Private lado3 As Integer

    Public Function cargarLados() As Object
        Return 1
    End Function

    Public Function obtenerPerimetro() As Object
        Return 1
    End Function

End Class
```

> Error 2   'Triangulo' cannot inherit from class 'Poligono' because it
>   expands the access of the base class outside the
>   assembly. c:\users\win7\documents\visual studio
>   2013\Projects\WindowsApplication1\WindowsApplication1\Form1.vb    33  14  WindowsApplication1

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default, [classes declared at the namespace level get `Friend` access level](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235296%28v=vs.120%29.aspx). So `Poligono` is `Friend Class`. A `Friend` class may not be made visible to general public.

Change

```
MustInherit Class Poligono
```

to

```
Public MustInherit Class Poligono
```

Answer (score 3):

Two things:

1. You have to add the return type with `As`

   ```
   Public MustOverride Function obtenerPerimetro() As Object
   Public MustOverride Function cargarLados() As Object
   ```
2. You have to add `Overrides` to the method that overrides the abstract base class

   ```
   Public Overrides Function cargarLados() As Object
       Return 1
   End Function

   Public Overrides Function obtenerPerimetro() As Object
       Return 1
   End Function
   ```